# How to prevent tmux from displaying date in new window

Tags: tmux

When I create new window in `tmux` it displays name of current directory and date:

```
Directory: /home/killy
nie, 4 lis 2012, 14:51:18 CET
[killy@xerxes : ~]
```

How can I prevent that?

EDIT: I realized that this problem appears when I set `TERM` variable to `xterm`.

Comment: See the [tmux FAQ](http://tmux.git.sourceforge.net/git/gitweb.cgi?p=tmux/tmux;a=blob;f=FAQ), TERM *must* be `screen` or a derivative thereof...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would expect these messages to be coming from your shell initialisation - either it is produced always by your shell init script or only in some mode, e.g. for interactive shells. As these lines are the default on many distributions, I would suggest to look into `/etc/profile` (look for the "Directory:" string). Using your own shell init scripts (for `bash` these would be `~/.bashrc` and `~/.bash_profile`), where you modify it to your liking, is probably the best way to go.

Comment: You are right. On my openSUSE the code responsible for this is located in `/etc/profile`. Thanks!

Comment: @JanStolarek By the way, putting all of your personal initialization stuff into ~/.bashrc has another advantage: it can be more easily shared across several machines since you don't need a write access to /etc to modify it. You can even track it with a version control system.